How to do math functions in point meta symbolic for color maps
I'm trying to have a repetitive colormap.
To do this, I'd draw the colorbar, and then moduli the color by the factor giving the number of repititions I want.
This looks something like the following MWE (Should repeat black->red colorbar 10 times):
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[view={0}{90},
        hide axis,
        shader=interp,
        mesh/color input = explicit mathparse,
                y domain=0:1,
                domain=0:10,
        ]
            \addplot3 [
                surf,
        variable=\x,
        variable y=\y,
        point meta={symbolic={rgb=mod(x,1),0,0}}, % <- switch out "mod(x,1)" -> "x/10" for working but wrong example
            ] (x,y,1);
        
    \end{axis}
    
\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}

This however gives an error, that the input to the mod operator is a wrongly formatted:
point_meta_symbolic_math.tex|21 error| Package PGF Math Error: Sorry, an internal routine of the floating point unit got an ill-formatted floating point number `0'. The unreadable part was near '0'. (in 'mod(x').

Is there a way to use simple math functions in the symbolic color calculations?
I can Repeat the code manually, going within the range 0 to 1 for the value, and then shifting the x-coordinate in the plot below.
This would however leave a small gap, so it is very fiddly (especially when changing the mod number). There are also places where it is less doable, for example in polar coordinates, In particular if trying to create a repetitive circular colorscale (repetitive version along the rotation of say: Correct use of axis cs).
Thanks for any help.

\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[view={0}{90},
hide axis,
]
\addplot3 [
surf, shader=interp,
domain=0:10, samples=100,
y domain=0:1, samples y=2,
mesh/color input=explicit mathparse,
point meta={symbolic={rgb={mod(x,1)},0,0}},
] (x,y,1);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}



Thanks, I feel stupid now 8-). Off course it's the old {} needed around more complicated operations. I know this is necessary for coordinate math, I don't know why I didn't realise it would be necessary here.

It is typically/always ( and ) that needs protection

Yes, I could imagine that the , might also need protection, given the context of the code. But I don't see why I would use a ,here without surrounding ()
